# Extremely basic boolean search parser. fail's beyond 3 levels

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am attempting to make an extremely basic boolean search parser that will be a modification to an existing system that is 20 years old. So i cant really change the db tables or add packages or anything to help me. All it should be able to do is handle AND, OR and NOT operations on a keywords table.

The query that I am generating is to slot into another big query that is built up from, various search fields. I am attempting to add this onto the keyword search part of it only. The db is Oracle (9i) and the field its searching (kw) stands for keywords and is a CLOB containing a bunch of keywords.

So if someone was to enter "andrew" or "koch"  not "Musselburgh" into the search box it would return all the "andrew's" and "koch's" that don't have Musselburgh as a keyword also. This works but if I go beyond three levels it wont work because the precedence of operators.

Here is the basic php code that can be easily ran:

```
$test = '"andrew" or "koch"  not "Musselburgh"';

$keywords = explode('"', $test);


//remove empty values from array
$keywords = array_filter($keywords);
//reset array keys
$keywords = array_values($keywords);
//remove any white space from array values
$keywords = array_map('trim', $keywords);
//var_dump($keywords);
$keywords = array_map('strtoupper', $keywords);

echo $test;
var_dump($keywords);

$and_terms = array();
$or_terms = array();
$not_terms = array();

foreach($keywords as $key => $value)
{

if($key === 0){
    continue;
}
else {
    if($keywords[$key-1] == 'AND'){
        $and_terms[] = $value;
    }
    else if($keywords[$key-1] == 'OR'){
        $or_terms[] = $value;
    }
    else if($keywords[$key-1] == 'NOT'){
        $not_terms[] = $value;
    }
}

} 


$kw_table = false;

$first_kw = $keywords[0];

$q = '';
$qn = '';

foreach ($and_terms as $kw){
    $q .= " AND UPPER(kw) LIKE '%$kw%'";
}

foreach ($not_terms as $kw){
    $q .= " AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%$kw%'";
    $qn .= " AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%$kw%'";
 }

 foreach ($or_terms as $kw){
    $q .= " OR ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%$kw%' {$qn} )";
 }


 if(!$kw_table){
   $w ="
        (
           c.cand_id in
          (
            select cand_id from cand_kw WHERE client_id='client_id' AND ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%$first_kw%'{$q} ) 
          )
        )";
 }
 else {
 $w ="
        (
           c.cand_id in
          (
            select cand_id from pbank.$kw_table where UPPER(kw) LIKE '%$first_kw%'{$q}
          )
        )";
 }

 echo $w;
```

If I enter "andrew" or "koch" not "Musselburgh".

You will see that it generates a query like this from the given input:

```
( c.cand_id in ( select cand_id from cand_kw WHERE client_id='client_id' AND ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%ANDREW%' AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%MUSSELBURGH%' OR ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%KOCH%' AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%MUSSELBURGH%' ) ) ) )
```

Which actually works and gives me back the correct results.

But if I use "andrew" or "koch" not "Musselburgh" not "Edinburgh" it generates this query

```
 ( c.cand_id in ( select cand_id from cand_kw WHERE client_id='client_id' AND ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%ANDREW%' AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%MUSSELBURGH%' AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%EDINBURGH%' OR ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%KOCH%' AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%MUSSELBURGH%' AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%EDINBURGH%' ) ) ) )
```

But this query does not work.

How can my code be modified to generate the queries correctly with the precedence of operators and all the bracket in the correct places? Or just be made to work better than it currently does.

I am no sql expert and this gives me a soar head.

Comment: The order of operators can vary? For example this query is valid? `"A" not "B" or "C" and "D"`?

Comment: Yeah I think that would be valid. But I think that is getting more complicated than its meant to be. As I dont want to include brackets just AND, OR and NOT

Comment: Well, no problem, but what the difference between: `"A" not "B" or "C" and "D"` and `"A" and "D" or "C" not "B"` and `"C" and "D" or "A" not "B"`?

Comment: @Anton You are saying it has to be A or Both (C and D), or it has to be (A and D) OR C but NOT B. (C and D) or A but B

Comment: And what about `A and B or C and D not E and F`?

Comment: would be E AND ((A and B) or (C and D))  NOT F but i am unsure how that would be in an sql query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221276/discussion-between-anton-and-user794846).

Answer (score 0):

It is about the brackets.

```
client_id = 123
AND
(
    (
        kw LIKE '%%'
        AND kw NOT LIKE '%%'
        AND kw NOT LIKE '%%'
    )
    OR
    (
        kw LIKE '%%'
        AND kw NOT LIKE '%%'
        AND kw NOT LIKE '%%'
    )
    OR
    (
    ...
    )
)
```

Move the `OR` part.

```
$q = '';
$qn = '';
$qo = ''; // NEW

foreach ($and_terms as $kw){
    $q .= " AND UPPER(kw) LIKE '%$kw%'";
}

foreach ($not_terms as $kw){
    $q .= " AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%$kw%'";
    $qn .= " AND UPPER(kw) NOT LIKE '%$kw%'";
 }

 foreach ($or_terms as $kw){
    $qo .= " OR ( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%$kw%' {$qn} )"; // CHANGED
 }


 if(!$kw_table){
   // CHANGED brackets and OR position
   $w ="
        (
           c.cand_id in
          (
            select cand_id from cand_kw WHERE client_id='client_id' AND (( UPPER(kw) LIKE '%$first_kw%'{$q} ) {$qo})
          )
        )";
 }
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZuRD1)

More complex scenarios will increase the complexity of the input (brackets, quotation marks, ...).

Comment: Thanks for the help not tested it or had time examine the code yet. How many levels can this handle?

Comment: @user794846 it can handle multiple `or` and `not` keywords. This will not work with multiple `and` keywords.

Comment: it seems to work with multiple AND. They end up inside the same bracket but that an issue?

Comment: Not if it provides the results you expect :)